# Maintenance page displayed upon deployment

Tags: git, github, ssh

I have a repository on GitHub that is linked with an account on https://www.deployhq.com/

In deploy HQ I am using SSH to connect to my server, so I am able to send SSH Commands when the deployment starts and when the deployment ends.

I am wanting to send a command to my server that forces a maintenance page to be displayed when the app is accessed, while the deployment is going on. And then once the deployment is done, I want to send another command that un-enforces the maintenance page being displayed.

My knowledge in SSH is **VERY** limited so I need a lot of help here. A search on google didn't really turn up anything.

**Update**

I am using CentOS 6 with a VPS from GoDaddy with SSH and cPanel.

I do have a maintenance page already, it is located at directorytoupdate/maintenance/index.php

Right now, I am using .HTACCESS to direct the app to the maintenance page.

```
# MAINTENANCE-PAGE REDIRECT
#<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  #RewriteEngine on
  #RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.456\.789\.000
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance/index.php/$ [NC]
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpg|jpeg|jpg) [NC]
  #RewriteRule .* /maintenance/index.php/ [R=302,L]
#</IfModule>
```

I comment/un-comment based on either I want maintenance mode enabled or disabled. I'm guessing we could re-write the .htaccess file on the beginning and ending of the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an `.htaccess` file for redirection, a simple solution could be a bash script copying and removing the htaccess file.  My knowledge of CPanel is limited, but I believe the default directory structure is `/home/(user)/public_html`. So you'd make a file named `begin-maintenance.sh` in your home directory:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp ~/public_html/website_directory/.htaccess ~/b.htaccess
cp ~/m.htaccess ~/public_html/website_directory/.htaccess
```

To use this, you'd change the paths to reflect the appropriate ones for your site, and you'd put the htaccess maintenance lines into a file name `m.htaccess`. The script would first backup your existing htaccess file, then overwrite it with the maintenance file. A reverse script, `end-maintenance.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp ~/b.htaccess ~/public_html/website_directory/.htaccess
```

You would need to make both scripts executable - most ftp clients can do this - and then simply call them from the ssh script with `~/begin-maintenance.sh` and `~/end-maintenance.sh`.

Comment: Wow. You make it look so simple! I will try this when I get off work! Excited!